# Customize katharsis json response

Tags: json, json-api, katharsis

I am using katharsis, I want customize response, following is the katharsis response.

```
 {
 "type": "table-name",
 "id": "A",
 "attributes": {
 "description": "AAA"
},
"relationships": {

 },
 "links": {
   "self": "http://localhost/table-name/A"
 }
}
```

How to remove ""self": "http://localhost/table-name/A"" under links?

Comment: I believe there is an open issue requesting this but it's currently not directly available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add String field in Katharsis Dto, give empty value to this filed.
Then add annoation @JsonApiLinksInformation. Katharsis will replace ""self": "http://localhost/table-name/A"" to an empty string

Comment: Do you have a sample output?

Comment: {
 "type": "table-name",
 "id": "A",
 "attributes": {
 "description": "AAA"
},
"relationships": {

 },
 "links": ""
}